# react-router-dom-v6 change useHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mern

```
const Routing=()=>{
  const Navigate=useNavigate()
  const {state,dispatch}=useContext(UserContext)
  useEffect(()=>{
    const user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
    if(user){
      dispatch({type:"USER",payload:user})
    }
    else{
      if(!history.location.pathname.startsWith('/reset'))
           Navigate('/signin')
      }
    },[])
```

Since I am using `react-dom-v6` , I know that I need to replace `history.location.path.startsWith('/reset')` with `Navigate` and I have seen posts but none is focused on this.

It would be really helpful if one can tell me!

Comment: What is the issue? is navigate not working?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') this is the error when I replace history with navigate

Comment: It doesn't look like it is related navigate. Maybe other thing causing the issue?
Try this `navigate("signin", { replace: true });`. If this does not work you have to add you working code or either create sandbox. Its hard to tell from this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. it is wrong to use useNavigate in this case. you can use useLocation hook. Your code should be like this.

```
const Routing = () => {
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const location = useLocation();
        const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext)
        useEffect(() => {
            const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
            if (user) {
                dispatch({ type: "USER", payload: user })
            }
            else {
                if (location.pathname.startsWith('/reset'))
                    navigate('/signin')
            }
        }, [])
```

You can check out react router v6
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#history-object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).